# TLS Client using libcurl,does not fail when client verification fails on server side

Tags: c++, openssl, libcurl

I have a C++ TCP client / server application encrypted with TLS. 
On the server side, I am using openSSL with peer verification. 
On the client side, I am using libcurl.

Everything works unless the client is using a certificate which fails verification. Here is a summary of the process when the client is using a bad certificate.

On the server side, the `SSL_accept` returns a failure code due to verification, which is expected.

On the client side, after doing:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 1L);
    r = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (r != CURLE_OK) {
        // ERROR
    } else {
        // OK
    }
```

The 'r' returns 'CURLE_OK', and my connection only fails when the client tries to send data and fails. My question is, why does it not fail after the first 'curl_easy_perform', which is 'CONNECT_ONLY'. Do I need to set up an additional parameter for libcurl? I would prefer to keep using libcurl instead of writing my own OpenSSL client.

Comment: The SSL handshake only needs to occur when you first send or receive data. If you just connect and disconnect you don't need to get into SSL mode at all.

Comment: I want to check the SSL handshake status (ok or not ok) from the start. Therefore I will need to do a write just to check the connection?

Comment: I'm sure OpenSSL has an API for starting the handshake.